# What should be done to a vector file when creating a business card?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design, cmyk, eps

Hello I'm creating a business card
Size 90mm by 50mm
It's going to be printed by offset printing
And I am using CMYK color system for the colors, the color of the icons for example the values are like this:
C 93%
M 28%
Y 65%
K 11%

But I downloaded a vector file as shown in image, format EPS, what should I do to it before sending the business card to be printed?

Can I combine the shapes together using shape builder tool?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are confusing a business card with a mini brochure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a PNG logo to design a business card?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/161294/can-i-use-a-png-logo-to-design-a-business-card)

Answer (score 4):

One *generally* doesn't need to "do" anything to a vector file specifically before sending it to a print provider.

That being posted, *standard* artwork issues apply - exceptionally small, minute, details or paths *may* not be maintained. Gradients *may* incur a bit of banding if not appropriately constructed, etc. But these issues aren't *specific* to vector files.

If the artwork is in the proper color space for the printing method (CMYK/RGB) then there should be no issue with a vector file.

Saving/Exporting to a PDF/X-1a format ensures everything matches press standards.